# after user input my if else else if loop, does nothing (CS50 pset1)

Tags: c, cs50

So im currently learning how to code in C, doing the CS50x course,
and on the Pset1 cash, after i type in  the user input, nothing is happing, i have gone for a if elseif loop,

so my question is where is the code wrong, or have my entire idea of a if else loop been wrong

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main (void)
{
    
    //Varibales for later use in code
   
    float a = 0.25;  
    float b = 0.10;
    float c = 0.05;
    float d = 0.01;
    float Cret;

    //how many coins needed A=.25 B=0.10 C=0.05 D=0.01
    int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
    int C = 0;
    int D = 0;
    //Gets User input
    do
    {
        Cret = get_float("Change owned:");

        //counts how many coins are needed
        do
        {
            if(Cret>a)
            {
                A++;
                Cret = Cret - a;
            }
            else if (Cret>b && Cret<a)
            {
                B++;
                Cret = Cret-b;
            }
            else if(Cret>c && Cret<b)
            {
                C++;
                Cret = Cret-c;
            }
            else if(Cret>d && Cret-c)
            {
                D++;
                Cret = Cret-d;
            }
        }
        while (0<Cret);
    }
    while(Cret>0);
    int coins=(A+B+C+D);
    printf("Coins back:%i",coins);
}
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Step thru your code in a debugger and examine the variable values as it runs. Or even just add debug print statements.

Comment: One problem: `else if(Cret>d && Cret-c)`. Spot the typo?

Comment: OT: regarding: `float a = 0.25;  
    float b = 0.10;
    float c = 0.05;
    float d = 0.01;`  this is trying to stuff `double` literals into `float` variables.  Much better to include a trailing `f` on each of those literals, so they are `float` values.  I.E. `float a = 0.25f;  
    float b = 0.10f;
    float c = 0.05f;
    float d = 0.01f;`

Comment: Don't use float our double for currencies at all. Instead use integers for the smallest denomination.

Comment: the variables: `int A = 0;
    int B = 0;
    int C = 0;
    int D = 0;`  have meaningless names, even in the current context.  Suggest: `int quarters = 0;
    int dimes = 0;
    int nickles = 0;
    int pennies = 0;`

Comment: strongly suggest:  extract all the quarters, then extract all the remaining dimes (cannot be more than 2), then extract all the remaining nickles (cannot be more than 1), then the left over amount, if any, is pennies (cannot be more than 4)

Comment: suggest:  to obtain number of quarters:  `cret / .25f ` then `cret = cret % .25f`  then to obtain the number of dimes: `cret / .10f` then `cret = cret % .10f`  ...... etc

Comment: @Yunnosch IKR, every one of these, every Sunday, it's 'float change;' or similar.  Maybe there's something wrong with the course:(

Answer (score 0):

This is the error

```
else if(Cret>d && Cret-c)
```

Change it to

```
else if(Cret>d && Cret<c)
```